# How to call stored procedure with named parameters from Oracle Call interface?

Tags: plsql, oracle-call-interface

I have a requirement to call PL/SQL stored procedure from Oracle Call interface program by passing named parameters. How to do that ?

Suppose I have a procedure

```
PROCEDURE MY_SWAP(X IN OUT NUMBER,Y IN OUT NUMBER) AS T NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        T := X;
        X := Y;
        Y := T;
    END MY_SWAP;
    /
```

I can call the procedure from sqldeveloper as follows by passing as named parameters.

```
MY_SWAP(Y=>B, X=>A);
```

Right now I am using the following. Using OCIBindByPos() to pass parameters in defind order in the declaration.

```
OCIStmtPrepare(...)
OCIBindByPos()
OCIStmtExecute()
OCIStmtFetch()
```

How to call the procedure with Oracle Call INterface to pass parameters as named parameters?

Comment: It would be helpful to include some code showing what you're attempting. TO you mean [named binds](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnoci/binding-and-defining-in-oci.html#GUID-BC53FC10-66C7-4803-A90D-57647B0A0C91) or argument names (like `call some_proc(p_arg => :value`)?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you are after. Your call can still be `MY_SWAP(Y=>:B, X=>:A)` or just `MY_SWAP(:B, :A)`, and you can use `OCIBindByName()` as shown in the docs I linked to. What isn't working?